# how to find the position of a rotated text?

Tags: android, bitmap, image-rotation

For example this is my image

[image]

i know the height and the width of the text and how much it has been rotated (the angle) i also know where the top left corner of the text is if it was not rotated for example:

[image]

i also know the position of the text center which text rotate around and that position doesn't change in the rotation

now i need to know if the user tap on the image whether it has been on the text or not if yes i also would need to know the offset

**EDIT**

here is the code responsible for rotating and positioning the text bitmap

```
public Bitmap getFullTextBitmap2(Bitmap hostBitmap) {
    Bitmap tempTextBitmap = getTextBitmap(); // getting the bitmap which only contain the text and has the height and width of the text
    Bitmap fullTextBitmap = hostBitmap.copy(hostBitmap.getConfig(), true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(fullTextBitmap);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(tilt - 180, textWidth / 2, textHeight / 2);
    matrix.postTranslate(position.getLeft(), position.getTop());
    if (isSelected) {
        Canvas textCanvas = new Canvas(tempTextBitmap);
        textCanvas.drawColor(selectedColor);
        textCanvas.save();
        textCanvas.restore();
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(tempTextBitmap, matrix, new Paint());
    canvas.save();
    canvas.restore();
    return fullTextBitmap;
}
```

Comment: so you are using ImageView with scale type == MATRIX, right? so use `Matrix#mapPoints` method

Comment: it's fit_center .
each new text that the user request cause a new image view to be instantiated and overlay the main image view. The newly instantiated image view is all transparent so the users sees the main image underneath. then on the transparent layer i paint the text which is not clickable.. when the user click on the image main image view get notified and send the touch location to all layer if any layer had any text at that position the text get selected this all works fine until you rotate the text @pskink

Comment: so how is the text rotated?

Comment: the text is bitmap contained in another bitmap (the big transparent one) when you rotate the text i use matrix.setRotate and matrix.postTranslate to position and rotate the text @pskink

Comment: so use `Matrix#mapPoints` as i already said

Comment: how to use `Matrix#mapPoints` this is my first app and i haven'd done much of java or image processing ... can you give some where to know more about this @pskink

Comment: sure: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pskink suggested I used:

```
Matrix#mapPointes
```

But I used it to undo the the user touch input and compare it with `none-rotated` bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Please register to the onclick event on the textView or imageView respectively to listen for their touches.

Comment: it's not a text view. and the imageView that contain the text is the same size as the main big picture. 
The text is added at run time and while it's not rotated i can interact with it but when it's rotated i have trouble finding it's location